# Select the month with the most recent data available and the previous month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is analogous in structure to the one defined below. The PK is the first 4 columns, the last column is the actual score. Each row is populated fully with the 12 months of the fiscal year, scores are filled in as the become available that month. Each month, we want to report on what the most recent available score is (some scores lag behind a month or two so we can't use the current month) and what the previous one was. Given the data supplied below, I would like the results to appear as such:

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------+
|ScoreKey|DeptName|TestName|ScorePeriod|ScoreValue|CurrentPrevious|
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------+
|    1   |  'abc' |  'def' |  201707   |   1      |   Current     |
|    1   |  'abc' |  'def' |  NULL     |   NULL   |   Previous    |
|    2   |  'abc' |  'def' |  201801   |   7      |   Current     |
|    2   |  'abc' |  'def' |  201712   |   6      |   Previous    |
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

I tried doing a `GROUP BY` with `MAX()` then `UNION` and filter out the `MAX` value but that doesn't account for ones with only one row of data (it returns no row).

Code to provide the table and values:

```
    create table #scores (
        ScoreKey INT,
        DeptName VARCHAR(10),
        TestName VARCHAR(10),
        ScorePeriod INT,
        ScoreValue INT
    )

    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201707,1)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201708,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201709,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201710,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201711,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201712,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201801,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201802,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201803,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201804,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201805,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (1,'abc','def',201806,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201707,1)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201708,3)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201709,4)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201710,5)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201711,5)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201712,6)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201801,7)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201802,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201803,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201804,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201805,NULL)
    insert into #scores values (2,'abc','def',201806,NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from 
( select * 
       , row_number over (partition by ScoreKey, DeptName, TestName order by ScorePeriod desc) as rn
  from table 
) aa
where rn <= 2
```